# Checking if subobject is true with function

Tags: javascript, function, object

Why doesn't this work? I want to check if subobject of object is true/false with this code, but when i try it it always returns false.

```
var testobject = {
    a:true,
    b:false
}

function test(check) {
    if (testobject.check) {
        console.log('it works')
    }
    else {
        console.log('it doesn\'t work')
    }
}
test('a');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `testobject.check` the `check` is an identifier for a property in the object, it's not the variable `check`.

Use bracket syntax to access properties using a string as name:

```
if (testobject[check]) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your testobject doesn't have a property called `check`. What you are looking for is `testobject[check]`

If you are using a string for a property, then you can use the bracket `[]` notation.

`testobject.a` is equivalent to `testobject["a"]`

Answer (score 0):

I usually reference objects with the array-style syntax when using strings.  Not sure if your way works, but this should.  I'll test out momentarily to verify:

```
function test(check) {
    if ( testobject[check] ) {
        console.log('it works')
    }
    else {
        console.log('it doesn\'t work')
    }
}
test('a')
```

Yep, works...here's a JSFiddle for it:

http://jsfiddle.net/yz34V/